# Entity property not found error in symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

In prod mode of symfony, I get the below error.

```
"message": "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 134 near 'stock = :sto': 
Error: Class AppBundle\\Entity\\CartItem has no field or association named stock",
```

Actually before few days I added a stock property in my CartItem Entity.

This is working in dev environment but giving error in prod environment.

Comment: have you updates your doctrine database shema after changing your Model on Prod?

Comment: thanks for sharing, i forgot to push that file, now all works